# Changing global variables in a ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I've been trying to get this right for quite some time, I'm trying to append the object from the first ajax call after the second ajax call. But the for loop seems to iterate the changing of the value to the last result before appending the information, having the last post appended every time.

```
    var scribjson = 
{
    "user_id" : localStorage.viewing,
};
scribjs = JSON.stringify(scribjson);
var scrib = {json:scribjs};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getScribbles.php",
    data: scrib,
    success: function(result)
    {     
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
        for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i+=1)
        {   
            var userjson = 
            {
                "user_id" : obj[i].user_id
            };
            userjs = JSON.stringify(userjson);
            var user = {json:userjs};
            localStorage.post = obj[i].post;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "getRequestsInfo.php",
                data: user,
                success: function(result)
                {     
                    var obj2 = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
                    $('#listOfScribbles').append("<tr><td><img id = 'small_pic' src = '" + obj2[0].profileImage + "'/></td><tr><td>" + obj2[0].firstname + " " + obj2[0].lastname + "</td></tr> ");
                    $('#listOfScribbles').append("<tr><td>" + obj[i].post + "</td></tr>");
                },
                error: function()
                {
                    alert('An Error has occured, please try again.');
                }
            });

        }
    },
    error: function()
    {
        alert('An Error has occured, please try again.');
    }
});
```

Comment: Judging from the title of your question, and the fact that I can't really find out what your problem is: To access a global variable, one might want to consider using `window.varName`

Comment: @Jeff I've tried creating a global variable outside and tried using it, but it gives the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ajax calls It looks like the all `success` functions of the inner ajax call are being called after the loop has ended, so `i` will always be the last iterated value.

Try this:

```
(function(i)
{

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getRequestsInfo.php",
        data: user,
        success: function(result)
        {     
            var obj2 = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            $('#listOfScribbles').append("<tr><td><img id = 'small_pic' src = '" + obj2[0].profileImage + "'/></td><tr><td>" + obj2[0].firstname + " " + obj2[0].lastname + "</td></tr> ");
            $('#listOfScribbles').append("<tr><td>" + obj[i].post + "</td></tr>");
        },
        error: function()
        {
            alert('An Error has occured, please try again.');
        }
    });
})(i);
```

This will create a closure on `i`, which will give each ajax call its own copy of the current value.

Comment: You do not need to wrap the entire ajax call. Wrapping the success handler is sufficient.

Comment: @Asad, you are right. I've chosen to wrap the entire ajax call because it seems more readable to me.

Comment: @Raphael Thank you, that worked perfectly, just a question, why would the ajax call only run after the loop though ?

Comment: Because ajax is asynchronous?

Comment: @Crossman, ajax requests are asynchronous. That means that the browser will send the request to the server and continue to execute the code. When the response arrives, it will call the `success` function, but a lot of code may have been executed meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Use an IIFE:

```
success: (function(i){return function(result) {
    var obj2 = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
    $('#listOfScribbles').append("<tr><td><img id = 'small_pic' src = '" + obj2[0].profileImage + "'/></td><tr><td>" + obj2[0].firstname + " " + obj2[0].lastname + "</td></tr> ");
    $('#listOfScribbles').append("<tr><td>" + obj[i].post + "</td></tr>");
}})(i),
```

etc. Currently your loop generated ajax success handlers contain a direct reference to the counter itself, which (by the time they are called) has reached its final value.